Horror novel where a babysitter is stalked by the kid she's baby-sitting. Part of his tools involve something like electronic LEGOs
I honestly don't remember exactly when I read this, at least 10 years ago, maybe over 20. I actually thought that I'd found the answer here, or on the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange, but I can find no reference to it. The protagonist is a babysitter who gets a job babysitting a young boy (I think adolescent). Part of my brain wants to say that she got the job after the untimely accidental death of the prior sitter. Something about the boy unnerves her, but she takes the job. I remember that the boy was extremely brilliant (and recognized as such by his parents), and frequently played with a toy that had him building circuits (robots?) by attaching cubes together in certain configurations. It was not futuristic technology, but definitely advanced. I think that the house also had an automated security system, and there might have been an early scene where the boy shows off his coding skills by having the security system address the babysitter by name.
The middle of the book is very hazy to me. I think maybe the boy is showing some degree of precocious sexuality and she has to fend off his clumsy advances? Ultimately, I remember that the climax had a massive storm which more or less leaves her trapped with him as he attempts to kill her, using the toy and the house computer to try to arrange accidents (although I remember one of them being more like a lethal shock than anything really accidental), and there's a scene where either she's sliding into a pit on mud made slick by the rain, or the boy is doing so and she has a chance to save him. Either way, it comes out that he did indeed kill the prior babysitter, and she survives the night (I don't recall if that involved his death).
I have a vague memory of it being a paperback, probably 200-300 pages. It was in English, and I'm pretty sure set in the United States, maybe somewhere in the Southwest. I don't remember ethnicities. In my brain, everyone is white, but that might just be me assuming that the races match my own.

Part of me is wondering if maybe I'm mashing together memories of R.L. Stine's The Babysitter 2. It has the protagonist encountering a creepy little boy with high intelligence who shows off his new computer to her and might have pushed one of her friends down the stairs in a fit of jealousy. He is not the killer, though. The ending does have them at a quarry (apparently the site of the prior book's climax). I may have to grab a copy and read through it.
